# Making columns from a range of lines in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file like the below:

```
A, B
1,2
3,4
5,6

C,D
7,8
9,10
11,12

E,F
13,14
15,16
```

As you can see, and imagine, when I import this data using pd.read_csv, pandas creates the whole thing making with two columns (A,B) and a bunch of lines. It's correct because of the shape. However, I want do create various columns (A,B,C,D...). Fortunately, there're a blank space at the end of each "column", and I think that this could be used to separete theses lines in some way. However, I don't know how to proced with this.

The data:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AlessandroMDO/Dinamica_de_Voo/master/data.csv

Comment: can you open the csv and paste a few rows from your ide? you must have a custom line terminator or something

Comment: Are the number of rows always the same? Also please make your input something that can be copied easily, like a 2d list.

Comment: Can you provide the above in a text box just do a simple copy & paste

Comment: I was trying to paste here but isn't working, so I put a link.

Comment: And yes, each "column" have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal behavior of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), but usually data is not stored in csv files this way.

You can try to read the csv, strip extra spaces and split it by empty lines to parts first. Then read each part using [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and concatenate them together using [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    parts = f.read().strip().split('\n\n')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(StringIO(part)) for part in parts], axis=1)
```

I have tried this with your csv:

```
    Alpha       Cd  Alpha       CL  Alpha  ...   Cnp  Alpha   Cnr  Alpha   Clr
0   -14.0  0.08941  -14.0 -0.19430  -14.0  ...   0.0  -14.0   0.0  -14.0   0.0
1   -12.0  0.07646  -12.0 -0.17150  -12.0  ...   0.0  -12.0   0.0  -12.0   0.0
2   -10.0  0.06509  -10.0 -0.14710  -10.0  ...   0.0  -10.0   0.0  -10.0   0.0
3    -8.0  0.05545   -8.0 -0.12150   -8.0  ...   0.0   -8.0   0.0   -8.0   0.0
4    -6.0  0.04766   -6.0 -0.09479   -6.0  ...   0.0   -6.0   0.0   -6.0   0.0
5    -4.0  0.04181   -4.0 -0.06722   -4.0  ...   0.0   -4.0   0.0   -4.0   0.0
6    -2.0  0.03797   -2.0 -0.03905   -2.0  ...   0.0   -2.0   0.0   -2.0   0.0
7     0.0  0.03620    0.0 -0.01054    0.0  ...   0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0   0.0
8     2.0  0.03651    2.0  0.01806    2.0  ...   0.0    2.0   0.0    2.0   0.0
9     4.0  0.03960    4.0  0.05879    4.0  ...   0.0    4.0   0.0    4.0   0.0
10    6.0  0.04814    6.0  0.12650    6.0  ...   0.0    6.0   0.0    6.0   0.0
11    8.0  0.06494    8.0  0.22050    8.0  ...   0.0    8.0   0.0    8.0   0.0
12   10.0  0.09268   10.0  0.33960   10.0  ...   0.0   10.0   0.0   10.0   0.0
13   12.0  0.13390   12.0  0.48240   12.0  ...   0.0   12.0   0.0   12.0   0.0
14   14.0  0.19110   14.0  0.64710   14.0  ...   0.0   14.0   0.0   14.0   0.0
[15 rows x 36 columns]
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, specify `index_col='Alpha'` in `read_csv` if you don't need duplicated Alpha column.